# LINQ: How do I perform an inline select statement in a LINQ statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WebOrder_URLHistory WHERE WebOrder_URLHistory.LeadID = Leads.LeadID) AS Sales
FROM 
    Leads
```

I want to put it (the select count statement) in this LINQ statement so I can get the sales count in my linq statement:

```
Dim TheLeads = (From L In DB.Leads Where L.IsDeleted = False Select L).ToList()
```

Is this possible to do in LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write `Select L, L.UrlHistory.Count()`